# No route matches [PUT] error in Rails 4.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am facing this error while running my application:

> No route matches [PUT] "/accounts/1/payment"

This is my form syntax;

```
<%= semantic_form_for(@account, :url => payment_path, :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
......
<% end %>
```

routes.rb:

```
get "/accounts/:id/payment" => "accounts#payment", :as => "payment"
```

controller method:

```
def billing
  @account = Account.find(params[:id])
  if request.put?
    // some code here
  end
end
```

Comment: did you add proper routes in `routes.rb`

Comment: You have to rename your action to `payment` or rename your route. see the below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
get "/accounts/:id/payment" => "accounts#payment", :as => "payment"
```

with

```
match "/accounts/:id/payment", to: "accounts#payment", :as => "payment", via: [:get, :put]
```

and let me know if this works.

**EDIT**

If your controller action is `billing`, then you may have to do

```
match "/accounts/:id/payment", to: "accounts#billing", :as => "payment", via: [:get, :put]
```

Answer (score 0):

your form is trying to find a route matches method put while your route has a get method.
Use put in routes instead of get

```
put "/accounts/:id/payment" => "accounts#payment", :as => "payment"
```

Comment: Now I am getting this error: `No route matches [GET] "/accounts/1/payment"`

Comment: oh in that case you may need both routes.

Answer (score 0):

In your form you are telling this form to be treated as `PUT` request but your routes says it is `GET` request. You should use same request type in both routes.rb and your form definition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
put "/accounts/:id/payment" => "accounts#billing", :as => "payment"
```